# VBA to lookup values from 2 columns in 3 other columns

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns, lookup

I'm a vba newbie but hoping I can find a simple solution to my problem. I am trying to look up values from 2 columns to see if they are found in another 3 separate columns but with a slight twist. Column G and H have first and last names respectively, whilst columns F and B have First Names that I want to search for a match and Column C has LastNames I also want to search. Basically I want Excel to check if Col G and H have the First Name, and if so, check if Col C has the last name. If all of this matches then write the "TRUE" to col I. I've tried using a nested IF statement such as this

`=IF(OR(G2=F2:F20000, G2=B2:B20000, AND(H2=C2:C20000)), "", "Not Found")`

This formula seems to work but if I drag it down the 20k rows it increments the formula ranges and messes up the search. I think this would be easier in a vba routine that I could run perhaps?

Help appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: As it looks to me, this is an array formula... I assume you want to check if there is one row which holds the name either in F or G and has the last name in C... I would suggest something like `IF(OR(((G2=$F$2:$F$20000)+(G2=$B$2:$B$20000))*(H2=$C$2:$C$20000)),"","Not Found)` as array formula (needs to be confirmed with ctrl + shift + enter)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need to use absolute references, like so.

```
=IF(OR(G2=$F$2:$F$20000, G2=$B2:$B$20000, AND(H2=$C$2:$C$20000)), "", "Not Found")
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I can now drag the formula down perfectly. However I am finding that the results seem to only be searching across the row and not the range I have specified. Is this a limitation of the IF statement?